# How do I get a sessiontoken from google place autocomplete API if I am working with the web service?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete, google-maps-autocomplete

Before I was using the Javascript widged from google autocomplete place and fine, it worked and there's a function so you get the sessionToken and you save some $$ in billing, but my PM wanted me to work using request to [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) and I cannot find any info or documentation on how to get these tokens using the API. Even in the [google video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL2rFahu9sLJ0pXNXfSiBlwqK4UidLIQWJ&v=VOP8cvCLGac) they mention the possibility of use the web service and use sessiontokens, but now, how do you make those?

I tried using the Javascript widget but that's not what the PM wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I found out was that even when the Javascript widget of Place Autocomplete brings a function itself to create the sessionToken, when you're using the Web Service **you have to make the sessiontoken BY YOURSELF**, and *this can be just any string*, but always have to be different, and google recommends to use UUID v4. So I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzqgVWli6k0) of a guy making the request using Flutter but I had to do it for my next.js app. Then I got to this npm library: [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and managed the state of a component variable with useState, added it to the request every time text changes:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
...
const [sessiontoken, setSessiontoken] = useState(null)
...
const handleInputChange = (text) => {
if(sessiontoken===null){
  setSessiontoken(uuidv4())
} ... }
```

And then put back to its initial state once the option has been clicked, consulted (place details), and saved.

```
...
setSessiontoken(null)
```